# How to return JSON response from a URL returning HTML

Tags: java, html, json, rest, craigslist

First, some background :-
I'm trying to solve a question asked by an interviewer recently. I had to write a code and use below URL to return JSON response -
https://losangeles.craigslist.org/

This is what I did :-
1) I created a webclient and made HTTPURL Request to fetch an HTTP Response.

```
public static JSONArray getSearchResults(String arg) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try {

        QueryString qs = new QueryString("query", arg);

        URL url = new URL("https://toronto.craigslist.ca/search?"+qs);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/text");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String readAPIResponse = " ";
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        while ((readAPIResponse = br.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(readAPIResponse);
        }

        jsonArray = convertToJson(output);
        System.out.println(" JSON response : "+jsonArray.toString(2));

        conn.disconnect();
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    return jsonArray;
}
```

2) Below was my function to convert the response into JSON :-

```
public static JSONArray convertToJson(StringBuilder response) {
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
    if (response != null) {
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.parse(response.toString());

            Elements resultRows = document.getElementsByClass("result-row");

            JSONObject jsonObj;

            for (int i = 0; i < resultRows.size(); i++) {

                jsonObj = new JSONObject();

                Element e = resultRows.get(i);
                Elements resultsDate = e.getElementsByClass("result-date");

                Elements resultsTitle = e.getElementsByClass("result-title hdrlnk");

                String key1 = "date";
                String value1 = resultsDate.get(0).text();
                jsonObj.put(key1, value1);

                String key2 = "title";
                String value2 = resultsTitle.get(0).text();
                jsonObj.put(key2, value2);

                jsonArr.put(i, jsonObj);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonArr;
}
```

The response I received was the whole HTML page(I used postman to make requests). Since, I only had few hours to solve this question and was not sure how to parse an entire HTML, I ended up using a third party library, called JSoup. I was not 100% happy about it, but ended up having no other option.

I have not heard back from them and I am curious if this was the worst approach and if yes, what could be better options? They did not mention anything about what technology I could use. But,since the skill set I was interviewing involved Java/J2EE I was thinking to implement this in Java (Not using Node js though)
Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answerable question without knowing _exactly_ what the interviewer is expecting. "How to convert HTML to JSON" is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Obviously this is not what the interviewer is asking. If you told us specifically: "We are supposed to request an HTML page, and scrap it for X data and return it in JSON format", that would be a suitable question, but it's not clear this is what the interviewer is asking.

Comment: pls clarify you question! What would you exactly know?

Comment: Thanks @PaulSamsotha for pointing it out. You are absolutely right! My bad. Yes, the question should be -  "We are supposed to request an HTML page, and scrap it for X data and return it in JSON format". Do you have any pointers? I will be trying the below answer too, but I'd love to have your recommendation as well!

Comment: @Niton, as framed by the interviewer , I only know that - " the craigslist URL needs to be accessed directly & it does not return JSON by itself" Hope it answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need an XML Parser which is obviously the base of HTML this is built in in the JRE core API.
Even in the SE Version the needed packages to parse exist:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.*;
```

Take a look at these classes they are the most important to parse or create an XML/HTML File

```
DocumentBuilderFactory
DocumentBuilder
Document
```

and here simple example for HTML

```
String text = "<html><head>HEAD</head><body>BODY</body>";
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
Document doc = builder.parse(input);
```